# Different Class Types, confused about Performance

Tags: c#, class, types

Okay there are many types of classes, and most, i do understand.

Public can be used all over the place

Private can only be use in that class

Protected was something like Private i think

So, the thing is Internal.

In a class file where i have DLLImports. I can either use, Internal or Public.
And both works, but i don´t really understand if there is a performance difference between them?

Here is the class.

```
namespace Capture
{
       internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        //USER32
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);
        //GDI32
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        internal static extern int BitBlt(
       IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, System.Int32 dwRop);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr obj);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        internal static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr obj);
    }

}
```

So everything is Internal, which i guess is good, as they can only be handed out from within the NativeMethods, so if i want to use them, i have to call NativeMethods.(what i want).

But, the class itself can be public or internal, both will work the same, as both are available to everyone. Does it have any impact on performance?

This has been asked before, but i am interested in Performance differences, not how every of them works as i know most of them (except my problem with understanding Internel/Public).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do access modifiers affect performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976676/do-access-modifiers-affect-performance)

Comment: I doesn't matter.Modifiers are being resolved at compilation time, not at runtime.

Comment: Well that topic didn´t actually have much of an answer, as all said different except the first comment. But got my answer now, both Tarec and alex:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance difference. The difference is that you cannot use internal classes from other assemblies.

Comment: Okay great, and well other assemblies is other solutions i guess?

Comment: This is the point of Object oriented, you set privacy level for classes, internal means that you can use these classes only inside the project/"assembly" you are in. Do you know what is assembly ? if not, check in google what is it.

Comment: @user2587718 An assembly, for the purposes of this discussion, is the output of compiling a *project*.